# Golang websocket nil memory error

Tags: go, websocket

Below is the code of my websocket server.

```
http.Handle("/gatewayconnector", websocket.Handler(socketHandler))
```

Method socketHandler has the code below:

```
func socketHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    LoadClient(ws)
    var msg []byte
    for {
        if err := websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg); err != nil {
            log.Error("Error in socketHandler: ", err)
            break
        }
        validateMessage(msg)
    }
}
```

The socket handler call back method get called when handshake happened from client and it also initiate the websocket object. So at very first step of this method i stored this websocket object into an array, so that i can retrieve it at the send method call (**used to send message to client**).

**The issue is sometimes I'm getting nil memory reference in ws i.e. the websocket while trying to send some message to client.**

Below is the send method code:

```
func Send(msg interface{}) error {
    ws := webSocketClients[0]
    if (ws == nil) {
        log.Error("Websocket connection is nil, gateway should initiate the connection.")
    }
    return websocket.JSON.Send(ws, msg)
}
```

**This issue arises when websocket connection remanis idle for a longer persiod of time and I call directly the send method.**

Right now i have put one hack that client will ping my websocket server at regular interval to avoid this.

How to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: If you have no already done so, run your program with the [race detector](http://blog.golang.org/race-detector) enabled. It might flag some issues in your application. Separate from whatever this problem is, take a look at the [Gorilla Websocket Package](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket).  The Gorilla package is better [maintained and has better protocol compliance than the x/net/websocket package](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#gorilla-websocket-compared-with-other-packages).

Comment: Looks like `webSocketClients[]` is a global array that's accessed from multiple goroutines (each socket handler HTTP request is its own goroutine). You'll need to use channels or mutexes to synchronise access to `webSocketClients[]` as concurrent access is not safe.

Comment: @MuffinTop sure i will run my program with race detector. I have looked into the Gorilla API, but the problem is how can i use the same websocket connection to send the message, as send message will be called as a separate unit. To cater this problem i kept this webscoket object in an array.

Comment: @Nadh thanks. For the time being i have only one client, but i will make use of mutexes for synchronization.

Comment: This is off track from the question, but the gorilla/websocket package has all of the functionality of the x/net/websocket package and more.  Even if you don't choose to use the gorilla package, you might want to take a peek at the  [examples](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#documentation). They are a good starting point for many types of applications can can be adapted to use x/net/websocket (after stripping important functionality like pinging).

Answer (score 1):

Pinging websocket connection on interval is normal thing to do, please check how it's done in [Gorilla Websocket Chat Example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat). I know you're using `net/websocket`, but the idea should be similar. The problem is that you can't rely that your long-time TCP connection will remain active, especially in public networks. Some firewalls silently RST connections without traffic flow after some period of time.